# How to prevent Elements BENEATH a Bootstrap Multiselect dropdown from firing on click of multiselect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

When a user clicks an option in a Bootstrap Multiselect dropdown a Bootstrap Toggle (http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) Element BELOW is fired.

I'm not sure if this problem is specific to Bootstrap Multiselect and/or Bootstrap Toggle, or the interplay of the two - it is the only Element in my app that overlaps/hides other Elements.

The plugin works great...it's just that when you click **Algebra** (1 below) or really any option in the dropdown, the Bootstrap Toggles below (2 in the screenshot) are fired as if you clicked them directly.

How do I prevent this without a check-to-see-if-the-multiselect-is-open logic?

[image: Screenshot of Multiselect]

Adding HTML to address question...the divs were inside a single parent div and I moved them to be in separate Divs...same result: clicking the dropdown multiselect fires the listener on `wordPref` class.

```
      <div class="row paddingMenu">
    <div class='col-xs-12 alignleft'>
      <b>Select</b> from <i>active</i> Libraries<a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click EDIT then ACTIVATE LIBRARIES to add and remove Libraries." tabindex="-1" class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign pull-right" style="font-size: 15px"></span></a>:
    </div>
    <div class='col-xs-12 aligncenter'>
      <div class='form-group'><select id='ddLibName' multiple='multiple'></select>
        <div id='ddLibrarySelect'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 aligncenter" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Choose whether to insert selected Comments as Word comment bubbles OR inline text.">
      <input type="checkbox" id="insertMode" class="wordPref" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small"
      data-off="Inline" data-on="Comment"
      data-offstyle="info" data-onstyle="success">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 aligncenter" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Save document owner/author info with your usage statistics. This setting may be defined by your institution.">
      <input type="checkbox" id="logMode" class="wordPref" data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small"
      data-off="History OFF" data-on="History ON"
      data-offstyle="info" data-onstyle="success">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 aligncenter">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="refreshBtn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Refresh AP to pull down any content changes or purchases." tabindex="-1">Refresh</a>
    </div>
    <div id='upsellMsgDiv' class='apSidebarAlert col-xs-12 hide'>
      <div class="spacer-5"></div>
      <div class="panel panel-warning">
        <div class="panel-body highlight-cell">
          <span class="apAlertMsg"></span>
          <div id='closeAlertBtn' class='col-xs-12 spacer-5  hide'>
            <button class='btn-sm btn-primary closeSidebarAlert pull-right' type='button'>Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but are those two inside a same div? Is one of them is a parent?.. Share your code as well... You can try doing

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

to the below div if the dropdown div is the parent div.

Comment: Thank you for looking...I added the HTML after trying to move to a different DIV...same result so far, but maybe you're onto something.

Comment: can you try removing the tabIndex once.. If possible can you post a js fiddle?

Comment: Or can you grab ddLibName and do e.stopPropagation() on 'click' event

Comment: Thank you for taking a look...the event was firing because of other processes, not a click 'through' the multiselect. I jumped to conclusions...although I'd seen similar behavior in another part of my app. Probably the same root cause.

Your suggestions helped me realize the flaw in my design - thank you!